# Getting DOM body from text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

I'm having issues with extracting the body from javascript code using getElementsByTagName.

```js
var enc1 = '<HEAD></HEAD><BODY>test</BODY>';
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = enc1;
var converted = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("body");
var res = "Body of text: " + converted;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/1a70rd4b/)

when I use converted, I get [object HTMLCollection].
When I use converted[0], I get undefined.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Neither [head](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-head-element) nor [body](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element) elements are valid inside a div. They must be children of an [HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element) element.

Comment: `var wrapper = document.createElement('html'); /* ... */ document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = converted[0].innerHtml;`

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? For instance, if you actually just want to get the text, you should be able to do `wrapper.textContent`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<head>` and `<body>` are a little bit more special than your everyday `<div>`s. You can only place them as direct descendants of `<html>`.

Creating a `html` tag like that is currently not possible with `createElement`, you will need to create a new `document` and then use it to access its `.body` property - `.body.innerHTML` to get the HTML.

The only ways to parse entire HTML documents are currently `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument` and `DOMParser`. `DOMParser` is a bit more fresh, so I would recommend using it.

```js
const enc1 = '<HEAD></HEAD><BODY>test</BODY>';
const newDocument = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(enc1, 'text/html');
const converted = newDocument.body.innerHTML;
const res = "Body of text: " + converted;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: *Otherwise it causes undefined behavior.* There's nothing undefined about it. HTML5 is very specific about how to handle parsing errors.

Answer (score 1):

`<body>` tags should never be inside a div. You can just do this to extract the text inside body:

`const bodyText = document.body.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Like RobG says in his comment, you cannot have a head or body tag inside a div.

Most, if not all, browsers will only write "test" to your wrapper div.

You have created the following with your code:

```
<div>test</div>
```

Thus the error happens when you attempt this line:

```
var converted = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("body");
```

There is no body tag inside your wrapper div and converted is therefore an empty HTMLCollection[].